# PHP Twitterify function regex doesn't exclude starting numbers

Tags: php, regex, twitter, hashtag

I'm using the code

```
function twitterify($ret) {
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $ret);
    return $ret;
}
```

to parse text from Tweets and add links. If #1 appears in the Tweet text then a hashtag link will be created for it. That's incorrect since hashtags can't start with numbers.

How can the regular expressions be modified to correct this?

Also special characters should be excluded according to [this](http://www.hashtags.org/platforms/twitter/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
/#(\w+)/
```

use this

```
/#([a-zA-Z]\w+)/
```

to make sure that the first character is a letter.

Comment: Thank you. That was simple enough.

Comment: Actually I just found [this](https://support.twitter.com/articles/370610-my-hashtags-or-replies-aren-t-working) where the hashtag rules are slightly different than I thought. The regex might not exactly match those rules, but I don't imagine using a hashtag that starts with a number in the future.